# Variable in export of package manifest

Tags: ros, manifest.xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a quick question about the neat wrapping of an external library. I'm wrapping PhysX into a ros package and would need an variable export of a cflag depending of the word-length of the host system.

```
cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/include/SDKs/Cooking/include -I${prefix}/include/SDKs/Foundation/include -I${prefix}/include/SDKs/NxCharacter/include -I${prefix}/include/SDKs/Physics/include -I${prefix}/include/SDKs/PhysXLoader/include" lflags="-L${prefix}/lib -Wl,-rpath,${prefix}/lib -lNxCharacter -lNxCooking -lPhysXCore -lPhysXLoader"
```

Now I want to add a flag `-DNX32` or `-DNX64` bit to the cflags depending on the host system. (The Makefile installs PhysX binaries automatically for 32bit and 64 bit systems into the package).

Any suggestions on how to nicely do this? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11421/variable-in-export-of-package-manifest/) by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2011-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Adding

```
-DNX`getconf LONG_BIT`
```

solved the problem.

```
rospack cflags-only-other physx2_wrapper: 
-DNX64
```

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) with karma: 191 on 2011-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) on 2011-10-05**:
Yep, that'll work.  You can see the same pattern in the way we call things like `rosboost-cfg` (e.g.: https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros_comm/trunk/clients/cpp/roscpp/manifest.xml).  But I'll note that this backdoor, where we let `bash` chew on the export flags, is highly non-portable, and will go away with the advent of `rosbuild2`.